# How to run automation using Selenium webdriver in IE10 with IE8 compatibility view

Tags: java, internet-explorer, selenium, internet-explorer-8

I am currently trying to automate my website testing using Selenium Webdriver(version 2.47.2) ,and i need to run the automation in IE 10 with IE8 compatibility view.
Is there any workaround to achieve this ?

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

(I am using Java for automation scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with **DesideredCapabilities**?

```
 ieCapabilities.setVersion("Version Number");
```

You can check out more here: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Another option is to:

```
 <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

but you'll need to change your code.